# cat command with a variable that has spaces

Tags: linux, command-line, bash, cat

I need to use `cat` command to display the contents of a file, and the filename has spaces in them: "embedded board link.rtf".

I assign the filename using a variable: `I="embedded board link.rtf"`, but when I use `cat $I`, I have this error message.

```
wireless-10-146-35-118 Desktop> cat $I
cat: embedded: No such file or directory
cat: board: No such file or directory
cat: link.rtf: No such file or directory
```

What might be wrong?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You have to quote the variable too:

```bsh
I="embedded board link.rtf"
cat "$I"
```

---

This is because the shell will first expand any variables, and then parse the command:

1. `cat $1`
2. `cat embedded board link.rtf`

When you really meant the following:

1. `cat "$1"`
2. `cat "embedded board link.rtf"`

---

Note that in `bash` and many other shells, variables inside single quotes will not be expanded:

1. `cat '$1'`
2. `cat '$1'`